# Which elements of the fundamental group of a surface can be represented by embedded curves?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Let $F$ be a closed orientable genus $g$ surface.  Which elements of $\pi_1(F)$ can be represented by simple closed curves?

I know that the standard generators can and I read the claim that if an element of $\pi_(F)$  can be represented by a simple closed curve and it is homologically nontrivial then it must necessarily be one of the standard generators.  Why is this true?

Additionally, if an element is homologically trivial then it is necessarily a product of commutators of the standard generators - which of these products of commutators can be represented by simple closed curves?

Any references are also appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where you wrote "homologically trivial", did you mean "homologically _non_-trivial"?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes - thanks for the correction!

Comment: I don't think there is an explicit answer for this question. Some partial answers are known. What you can say certainly is that an element of $H_1(S_g\mathbb Z)$ can be represented by a simple loop iff the element is a primitive element of the group.

Comment: Regarding your first question, do you know Whitehead's algorithm for determining whether an element of a free group is a member of a free basis? If so, I believe that there is an analogous algorithm to answer your question in $\pi_1(F)$. It's not the kind of thing that's been written down as far as I know, but it's the kind of thing that "experts would know", and it should be relatively easy to write down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the work of Birman and Series  I believe.  [Here](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ejb/b-series-algorithm.pdf) is a paper they wrote which looks at this for simple closed curves on orientable surfaces with boundary.  I know that there is a paper for surfaces without boundary, also by Birman and Series, which came out after this one, but I cannot find it at the moment.  I will look around and let you know if I find the other paper, but maybe someone else knows where it is.

They give an algorithm which lets you determine if a word in $\pi_1(F)$ represents a simple closed curve on the surface.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer to the second and third questions.

The third question has a general answer: In any group, the kernel of the abelianization (i.e. the set of homologically trivial elements of the group) is generated by the conjugates of the commutators of any generating set.

For the second question, the claim you reported reading is fuzzy and hence inaccurate. The correct statement is that if an element $\gamma \in \pi_1(F)$ can be represented by a homologically nontrivial simple closed curve then there exists an automorphism $\Phi : \pi_1(F) \to \pi_1(F)$ such that $\Phi(\gamma)$ is one of the standard generators.

To prove this, first, each of the standard generators is represented by a nonseparating simple closed curve.

Second, the simple closed curve representing $\gamma$ is nonseparating (otherwise the homology class is trivial).

Third, for any two nonseparating simple closed curves $c,d$ passing through the base point there exists a homemorphism $\phi : F \to F$ taking base point to base point such that $\phi(c)=d$. This is true because $F-c$ and $F-d$ are homeomorphic (an easy appplication of the classification of surfaces), and a homeomorphism between them can be found which extends over $c$ and $d$ to be a homeomorphism of $F$ that takes base point to base point.

Finally, the desired automorphism $\Phi$ is represented by the homeomorphism $\phi$.